# Azure function - adding function keys to Http triggers, or connection strings causes downtime?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function in production where I need to add a few new function keys on an Http trigger and a new connection string (when I mean new, it is really new, it is not replacing another one that already exists).

My doubt is if this causes downtime or if it requires restarting the function app in order to grab the new settings, can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you consider using [Deployment Slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#manage-settings) , give you advantage of fallbacks, per-warnings and waiting time of starting/restarting.

Answer (score 1):

When you make changes to application setting the host process needs to be restarted to pick up the latest/new values. You can find same details [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1a75fa6-e5de-43f5-bb34-a57a1389c770/does-changing-an-application-setting-cause-a-function-restart?forum=AzureFunctions). So you may face some downtime due to restart of your application.

Also same mentioned in azure-functions-host github as quoted below. Please refer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4797).

> Once an App Settings value is updated function runtime will be restarted and new value will be picked up.

Any change to application setting will restart your application no matter programmatically or manually using portal. You get same message when you're doing it manually -

[image]